# JavaScript code that does not run after editing WRONGLY

Tags: javascript

Guy please i need help with this javascript code. It's  not a code i wrote myself coz am still learning Javascript. Anyway, the code is supposed to create and process an online examination and give out the result. The code was fine at first until i touched something. If only anyone could edit the code for, i would be VERY MUCH GREATFUL. thanx in advance guys.
here's the code;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
<style>
div#test{border:#000 1px solid; padding: 10px 40px;}
</style>
<script>
var pos = 0, test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB,chC, correct = 0;
var questions = [
    [ "what is 10 + 4?", "12", "14", "16", "B" ],
    [ "what is 20 - 9?", "7", "13", "11", "C" ],
    [ "what is 7 x 3?", "21", "24", "25", "A" ],
    [ "what is 8 / 2?", "10", "2", "4", "C" ]
];
function _(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
}
function renderQuestion(){
    test = _("test");
    if(pos >= questions.length){
        test.innerHTML= "<h2>you got "+correct+" of "+questions.length+" questions correct</h2>";
        _("test_status").innerHTML="Test completed";
 pos = 0;
 correct = 0;
 return false;
    }
    _("test_status").innerHTML = "question "+(pos+1)+" of "+questions.length;
    question = questions[pos][0];
    chA = questions[pos][1];
    chB = questions[pos][2];
    chC = questions[pos][3];
    test.innerHTML = "<h3>"+question+"</h3>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'>"+chA+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'>"+chB+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'>"+chC+"<br><br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>submit Answer</button>";
}
function checkAnswer(){
    choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
    for(var i=0; i<choices.length; i++){
        if(choice[i].checked){
     choice = choices[i].value;
        }
    }
    if(choice == questions[pos][4]){
        correct++;
    }
    pos++;
    renderQuestion();
}
window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion, false);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2 id="test_status"></h2>
<div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Did you look at the error in your console. It tells you the problem.

Comment: choice and choices

Comment: Tell us what is the error you're getting and is this your homework ? if so you should try to solve it before asking here.

Answer (score 1):

You reference choice (e.g. `if(choice[i].checked)`) but the array is called choices. Replacing *choice* with *choices* fixes the issue as you can see below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
<style>
div#test{border:#000 1px solid; padding: 10px 40px;}
</style>
<script>
var pos = 0, test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB,chC, correct = 0;
var questions = [
    [ "what is 10 + 4?", "12", "14", "16", "B" ],
    [ "what is 20 - 9?", "7", "13", "11", "C" ],
    [ "what is 7 x 3?", "21", "24", "25", "A" ],
    [ "what is 8 / 2?", "10", "2", "4", "C" ]
];
function _(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
}
function renderQuestion(){
    test = _("test");
    if(pos >= questions.length){
        test.innerHTML= "<h2>you got "+correct+" of "+questions.length+" questions correct</h2>";
        _("test_status").innerHTML="Test completed";
 pos = 0;
 correct = 0;
 return false;
    }
    _("test_status").innerHTML = "question "+(pos+1)+" of "+questions.length;
    question = questions[pos][0];
    chA = questions[pos][1];
    chB = questions[pos][2];
    chC = questions[pos][3];
    test.innerHTML = "<h3>"+question+"</h3>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'>"+chA+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'>"+chB+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'>"+chC+"<br><br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>submit Answer</button>";
}
function checkAnswer(){
    choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
    for(var i=0; i<choices.length; i++){
        if(choices[i].checked){
     choices = choices[i].value;
        }
    }
    if(choices == questions[pos][4]){
        correct++;
    }
    pos++;
    renderQuestion();
}
window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion, false);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2 id="test_status"></h2>
<div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: WHAT??? THANX SOO MUCH MAN. Unlike some other languages that display the lines of error, JS can be very annoying if you don't go through the lines yourself. Again, Thanx.